# Actual look of rectangle is not working

Tags: java, swing, drawing, drawimage, drawrectangle

Below, you can see the shortened version of my code in which there is a mistake. I am working on a program resembling MS Paint. The problem is that when I want to draw e.g. a rectangle and I want to see how the painted rectangle will actually look like, then all previous rectangles up to the final are drawn by the program. Then, if look at commented parts of the code and use them with slight changes (not using former code), then it works the way I want it to work. However, then the program would have to save the picture into the memory of PC and I do not want it to work this ways. I am quite a beginner in JAVA and I absolutely do not know where the mistake may be, given that method `drawImage` requires type Image and that is what I am doing.

Hopefully you can understand what I am talking about. If by a chance you cannot, it is easy enough to copy the code a try it out. When you try drawing the first object, you will see the mistake.

First class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyPaint extends JFrame{

    private Desk paintDesk;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        MyPaint frame = new MyPaint();                              
    }   
    MyPaint()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
        setBounds(400, 100, 600, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        paintDesk = new Desk();

        this.getContentPane().add(paintDesk,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Desk extends JComponent{

    private Image paintedImage;
    private Image newImage;     
    private Graphics2D graphics;    

    private Point a;
    private Point b;

    public Desk()
    {   
        a= new Point();
        b= new Point(); 

        setDoubleBuffered(false);   

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){            
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){             
                if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
                {       
                    /*try {
                        ImageIO.write((RenderedImage)paintedImage, "JPG", new File("actual.jpg"));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                    newImage= paintedImage;
                    a.x = e.getX();
                    a.y = e.getY();             
                }                       
            }
        }); 

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){         
                if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
                {   
                    /*try {
                        newImage= (ImageIO.read(new File("actual.jpg")));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }*/

                    if(newImage!=null)
                    {
                        graphics.drawImage(newImage,0,0,null);
                        repaint();
                    }

                    b.x = e.getX();
                    b.y = e.getY();
                    if(graphics != null)
                    {
                        drawRect();
                    }                       
                    repaint();      
                }               
            }           
        }); 

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){        
                if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))     
                {                       
                    b.x = e.getX();         
                    b.y = e.getY();                 
                    if(graphics != null)
                    {                       
                        drawRect();     
                    }                   
                    repaint();                                  
                }               
            }
        }); 
    }   
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){             
        if(paintedImage == null)
        {
            paintedImage = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            graphics = (Graphics2D)paintedImage.getGraphics();
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
            clear();        
        }       
        g.drawImage(paintedImage, 0, 0, null);
    }   
    private void clear()
    {       
        graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics.setPaint(Color.red);
        repaint();
    }   
    private void drawRect()
    {
        graphics.drawLine(a.x, a.y, b.x, a.y);
        graphics.drawLine(a.x, a.y, a.x, b.y);
        graphics.drawLine(a.x, b.y, b.x, b.y);
        graphics.drawLine(b.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic approach of always painting to the image is wrong. You don't want to draw the rectangle on the image until the user releases the mouse button. Up until then you need to draw a temporary rectangle on the component in the paintComponent() method.

See the `DrawOnImage` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example that uses the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of this specific problem was, that I saved in variable newImage only the reference to a variable paintedImage and not a specific image.

newImage variable must be declared as BufferedImage and instead of code

```
newImage = paintedImage;
```

have to be this code:

```
newImage = new BufferedImage(getSize().width, getSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = newImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(paintedImage, 0, 0, null);
```